# Show $AA^+$ is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, pseudoinverse

Can somebody show me how $AA^+$ is symmetric if $A^+$ is the pseudoinverse of $A$?

All I can muster is:

$(AA^+)^T => (A^+)^TA^T$

I know: $(A^+)^T = (A^T)^+$ but that doesn't really seem like it gets us anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: If it's the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse), then $AA^+$ is Hermitian by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from user759562 is correct, it is Hermitian by definition. But in the spirit of the question, lets do the computation with the definition provided [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse). That is, when $A$ has linearly independent columns, $A^+$ can be expressed as $A^+ = (A^*A)^{-1}A^*.$ Note that for an invertible matrix $B$, we have $(B^*)^{-1} = (B^{-1})^*.$ Also, if you are working in the reals, just replace $B^*$ with $B^T$.

We wish to show that $(AA^+)^* = AA^+.$

We have \begin{equation} 
\begin{split} 
(AA^+)^* &= (A^+)^*A^* \\ 
&= [(A^*A)^{-1}A^*]^*A^* \\ 
&= A[(A^*A)^{-1}]^*A^* \\ 
&= A[(A^*A)^*]^{-1}A^* \\ 
&= A(A^*A)^{-1}A^* \\ 
&= AA^+.
\end{split} 
\end{equation}

This can be shown for the 'other' definition (ie. when A has linearly independent rows) using a similar sequence of steps.